# Clojure Defn returning empty parentheses just after displaying correct answer

Tags: clojure, lisp, parentheses, defn

I am trying to get only one zodiac name to past it down to different function, but I don not know why I ma getting empty parentheses after displayed zodiac. I am newbie with Clojure.

```
(defn miko []
                        (let [guess (read)]  
                        (remove nil?(cond 

                             (some #(= guess %) (range 101 120))(println "Capricorn")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 120 219))(println "Aquarius")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 219 321))(print "Pisces")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 321 420))(print "Aries")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 420 521))(print "Taurus")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 521 621))(print "Gemini")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 621 723))(print "Cancer")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 723 823))(print "Leo")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 823 923))(print "Virgo")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 923 1023))(print "Libra")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 1023 1122))(print "Scorpio")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 1122 1221))(print "Sagittarius")
                             (some #(= guess %) (range 1221 3112))(print "Capricorn")
                             :else "wrong"))))
```

> I run it (miko) and this is the result:
>
> Capricorn
>
> ()

Please help me to remove this , because when I want to pass down the result name for example Capricorn to another function, it passes down ()-parentheses instead.

Comment: that is the result of print.  if you want to return the strings there get rid of the `(print X)` and just use `X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing all right, just remove the print statements, for example replace `(print "Capricorn")` with `"Capricorn"`, and the function will work.

You also don't need the `(remove nil? ...)`

Comment: Thank you for helping me out Leonid!!!! It s working great now!!!! You comment helped me to understand clojure a bit more. I just have started learning it yesterday, so still much before me.

Comment: @user3297995 If you've used other programming languages before, it's not all that dissimilar.  E.g., printf in C returns an int.  That means that if you print the result from printf, you get something other than the output that was printed.  If you do `printf("%d",printf("Capricorn"));` you'll see "Capricorn" and "9".  Clojure's print happens to return (), so you see "Capricorn" and "()".

Comment: The last part is unfortunately wrong. `contains?` is a frequent false friend for people coming from other langs, because it doesn't look at the values in the given collection. It takes an associative collection and checks whether the given *key* exists in it. A range is not an associative collection, so using `contains?` on one gives an IllegalArgumentException.  To test for membership in a seq you would want to use `some`. In this case it seems even easier to just check with a comparison operator (e.g. `#(<= 111 % 222)`) though.

Comment: @user1571406 Thanks! Indeed a double comparison is more appropriate.

Comment: How would you change this line: (some #{guess} (range 101 120))(println "Capricorn") to work with decimal value like for example : (some #{guess} (range 1.01 1.20))(println "Capricorn"). When I change it to decimals it s not seeing the difference between 1.01 and 1.23 for example. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3297995 there's an example two comments up with the comparison operator: `#(<= 1.01 % 1.23)` - in Clojure this means `1.01 <= % <= 1.23`.